# Converting a sequence of bytes to ASCII representation and vice-versa

Tags: c++, string, stl

Suppose we have a vector of uint8_t: `{ 0x12 0x34 0xab 0xcd }`. I've found that I can use ostringstream in order to convert it to a string `"1234abcd"` (no spaces, no `0x` prefixes). But I couldn't simply convert it back with istringstream, apparently since it has no spaces. `hex` + `setw(2)` manipulators didn't help. Are there any easy ways to convert such strings to corresponding byte sequences (other than writing my own parser, at least)? Introducing spaces and other delimiters in the ASCII string is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a proxy object that reads precisely two characters from your `istringstream`

```
struct U8 {
  unsigned int datum;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&is, U8& u) {
    char s[3] = "xx";
    if(!((is>>s[0]) && (is>>s[1]) && (std::istringstream(s) >> std::hex >> u.datum)))
      is.setstate(std::ios::badbit);
    return is;
  }
  operator unsigned int() const { return datum; }
};
```

You would use it thus:

```
U8 nextByte;
iss >> nextByte;
std::cout << nextByte;
uint8_t ch = nextByte;
```

A complete program follows:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

typedef std::vector<unsigned char> V;

std::string Stringify(const V& v) {

  std::ostringstream oss;

  oss << std::hex;
  for(V::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
    oss << std::hex << (unsigned int)*it;
  }
  return oss.str();
}


struct U8 {
  unsigned int datum;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&is, U8& u) {
    char s[3] = "xx";
    if(!((is>>s[0]) && (is>>s[1]) && (std::istringstream(s) >> std::hex >> u.datum)))
      is.setstate(std::ios::badbit);
    return is;
  }
  operator unsigned int() const { return datum; }
};

const V UnStringify(const std::string& str) {
  V v;
  std::istringstream iss(str);

  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<U8>(iss),
            std::istream_iterator<U8>(),
            std::back_inserter(v));

  return v;
}


int main() {
  V v;
  v.push_back(0x12);
  v.push_back(0x34);
  v.push_back(0xab);
  v.push_back(0xcd);

  std::cout << Stringify(v) << "\n";
  assert(v == UnStringify("1234abcd"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can feed your istringstream by pair of characters in a cycle. i am sure )
use .str()

Comment: obviously not so efficient as parsing by hand, but who knows.
i think there will be no memory allocations at least.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way, I believe, but still:

```
void BytesToString(unsigned char* bt, char* str)
{
 int len = sizeof(bt);

 for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
 {
  sprintf(str + i*2, "%2.2x", bt[i]);
 }
}

void StringToBytes(char* str, unsigned char* bt)
{
 unsigned int sz = strlen(str);
 if ((sz % 2) == 1)
 {
  //was too lazy to prepend 0 to the string or write a separate case for that one, whatever

  puts("Bad input #1");
 }

 memset(bt, 0, sz/2);

 unsigned char temp = 0;
 for (unsigned int step = 0; step < sz; step++)
 {
  if (str[step] >= 0x30 && str[step] <= 0x39) {temp = (unsigned char)str[step] - 0x30;}
  else
   if (str[step] >= 0x61 && str[step] <= 0x7A) {temp = (unsigned char)str[step] - 0x57;}
        else {/* Is not an ASCII HEX string (illegal character) */   puts("Bad input #2");}

  bt[(step - step % 2) / 2] += temp*(0x01 + 0x0F*(!(step % 2)));
 }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not really C++'? This IS C++.

Comment: Using functions from C standard in C++ != C

Comment: If it looks like C, and works like C, well, it is C :) Mixing C and C++ code is sometimes necessary (while implementing OO-abstractions of old-style APIs, for example), but should be avoided whenever possible. I'm not implying that your answer is wrong or bad; but it is not generic and will not work with arbitrary containers, for example. It is a C way.